# Azure DevOps YAML pipeline: Jenkins Queue job output variable

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have set up a build and release pipeline in azure DevOps. We currently define the build pipelines as `YAML` but the release pipelines are set up in the UI due to lack of functionality in the `YAML` schema.

The task Jenkins queue job has an output variable which gives you the Jenkins Job ID that has been queued.

Setting this in the UI is straightforward, however setting in the `YAML` schema does not seem possible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/jenkins-queue-job?view=azure-devops

[This image shows the setting of the output variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLgCU.png)

[This image shows the use of the output variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjSLD.png)

I have tried to follow this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

But do not seem to be able to get it to set the output variable.

Starting to think it may not be available in the `Yaml` schema as clicking view `YAML` on the one I have set up in the release pipeline does not show the reference name.

Comment: this is weird, I would expect this to be available on all the steps, but I dont see this in the docs

Comment: Continued digging on this and found it needs refName setting but this doesn't seem possible in yaml.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, if you want to use `JENKINS_JOB_ID` as output variable, you can try without setting the reference name.

`queue Jenkins job task` publishes a output variable `JENKINS_JOB_ID`. It fetches the current job queued and emits the job id in this variable. you can mention `$(xxx_JENKINS_JOB_ID)` in the download task. `xxx` refers to the task name.

All the task output variables are namespaced. The default namespace is the task name.

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8201) in github for details.

Comment: I've tried this solution but it does not set the output variable. If you have seen it working please let me know.

Comment: @John Metcalfe I update the answer , please view it. You can try without setting the reference name in output variable.